# Windows CMD omite carácter ñ y caracteres con tilde al leer la entrada de teclado desde aplicación Dart

Tags: vscode, dart, cmd, utf-8, caracteres

¡Hola a todos!

La cuestión de fondo es que, programando en Dart, no consigo leer el carácter 'ñ', ni aquellos que portan tilde, que introduce el usuario mediante el teclado.

He escrito un código para intentar conseguirlo.

Este código lee una línea del teclado, codificada en utf-8. Luego la convierte a Lista de enteros que, en cada posición, contiene el valor Unicode del carácter en cuestión.
El código muestra el contenido de dicha Lista (para verificar su corrección) y también la línea de teclado decodificada de Latin1 a String.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> args) {

  String cadena = ( stdin.readLineSync( encoding: utf8 ) ?? '' );

  for ( final item in cadena.codeUnits ) {
    stdout.write( item.toRadixString( 16 ) + ' ' );
  }
  stdout.write( latin1.decode( cadena.runes.toList() ) );

}
```

He configurado el teclado en Español de España, VSCode en UTF-8, CMD en UTF-8, configuración regional en W11 (Beta) a UTF-8. He probado a instalar Vista Previa de Terminal de Windows. He puesto chcp 65001. También he probado intentando configurar todo a Latin1, aunque no sé si esto lo he hecho bien del todo. He intentado variaciones del código también.

El problema es que al ejecutar el código e introducir una línea de teclado con caracteres 'ñ' y 'con tildes', CMD los descarta por sistema.

La única manera en que los reconoce es pasando la entrada desde un archivo, con lo cual no es posible la interacción directa del usuario.

Ejemplo de ejecución con interacción directa del usuario (la primera línea es la entrada tecleada, la segunda el resultado obtenido):

```
ñaáeéiíoóuú
0 61 0 65 0 69 0 6f 0 75 0 aeiou
```

Si os fijáis, siempre lee como 0 los caracteres en cuestión, y no los muestra en la cadena impresa por pantalla.

Ejemplo de ejecución mediante un fichero 'entrada.txt' que hace las veces de teclado (redirección de entrada estándar):

```
f1 61 e1 65 e9 69 ed 6f f3 75 fa ñaáeéiíoóuú
```

Este resultado sería correcto, pero quiero conseguirlo sin tener que redirigir la entrada estándar.

El contenido del fichero 'entrada.txt' es el siguiente (incluye un salto de línea al final):

```
ñaáeéiíoóuú
```

Y el comando ejecutado en CMD:

```
dart prueba.dart < entrada.txt
```

Por favor, ¿alguna idea?